# SQL Creating a new column with previous dates in new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I would Like get below result in SQL Server (Color Coded)

The Column Required is How I would like my Dates to be:

[image]

Or this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NRn1.jpg

The new dates have to be specific to that ID

I was thinking of creating a new column of sequence(1, 2, 3,...) number per ID and another column where it is incremented by 1 (NULL, 1, 2, 3) and then doing a self left join.

Please advice on any other procedure and help with the code

Thanks

Comment: please post expected result and sample result as text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LEAD` and `LAG`

Syntax

```
LEAD (scalar_expression [,offset] [,default])
    OVER ( [ partition_by_clause ] order_by_clause )

LAG (scalar_expression [,offset] [,default])
    OVER ( [ partition_by_clause ] order_by_clause )

SELECT    Id, Date
        , LEAD(Date) OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS [Next Date]
        , LAG(Date) OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS [Prev Date]
        , LEAD(Date, 2) OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS [2nd Next Date]
        , LAG(Date, 2) OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS [2nd Prev Date]
        , LEAD(Date, 2, 0) OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS [2nd Next Date]
        , LAG(Date, 2, 0) OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS [2nd Prev Date]
FROM    @Test_table
```

Comment: Hi, Will this work for all my data, as my data has about 20,000 rows and is sensitive, which is why i could not post here

Comment: Run this query change  @Test_table to your table name and test.

Comment: Thanks I did a little tinkering to your code :  SELECT   ID, Date
               , LAG(Date,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY  ID ,Date) AS [Prev Date]
        FROM    [Table]      This gave me the lag output within each ID

Comment: I tried to up vote by my reputation is at 2 or 3 so it wont show LOL

Answer (score 1):

You can put your table in CTE with ROW_NUMBERs and then join this CTE with itself:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT  y.ID,
        y.[DATE],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY y.ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
FROM YourTable y
)

SELECT  c.ID,
        c.[DATE],
        c1.[DATE]
FROM cte c
LEFT JOIN cte c1 
    ON c.ID = c1.ID AND c.RN = c1.RN+1
```

Output:

```
ID          DATE        DATE
a2cVqAAl    6/16/2015   NULL
a2cVqAAl    6/24/2015   6/16/2015
a2cVqAAl    6/15/2015   6/24/2015
a36E8AAl    10/16/2015  NULL
a36E8AAl    7/8/2015    10/16/2015
d3yAAA      7/10/2015   NULL
d3yAAA      7/30/2015   7/10/2015
d3yAAA      9/9/2015    7/30/2015
d3yAAA      7/10/2015   9/9/2015
d3yAAA      7/14/2015   7/10/2015
d3yAAA      7/14/2015   7/14/2015
```

Comment: Well since I have SS 2012 the lag function worked for me. but ill give this a try as any logic is good  :p

Comment: Hi! You haven't specified the version of SQL Server, so I gave a general solution. :)

Comment: If any of the answers help feel free to upvote/accept them!

Comment: I tried both it helped but realized i needed more conditions to partion by

Comment: If there is some column (or there combination) which provides 100% guaranteed row order - it would be great in that case!