# SQlite3 Populate new column with another column's previous rows values

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I want to achieve almost exactly what's given in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223109/sql-creating-a-new-column-with-previous-dates-in-new-column), but the LEAD and LAG functions are unsupported in SQlite3.

**I want to fill a column of the existing table, with the values of another column but offset by one row**

I've searched for quite a while, but I cannot find a suitable alternative.

Assuming there are 100 rows of data, and the new column is already created (and full of junk values), the below code for me yields no result at all. The values remain as junk (unchanged).

The most I've managed travelling down this rabbit hole, is this:

```
    for i in range(1, 99):  
        cur.execute('''UPDATE myTable
                       SET a = (SELECT 
                                    CASE WHEN id > 1
                                    THEN b
                                    ELSE 0
                                    END
                                AS b
                                FROM myTable     
                                WHERE id = %d)
                     ''' % i)
```

As per my understanding of the above,
1. IF id < 1, a = 0
2. IF id > 1, a = b, where id = i, and i trails behind by 1.

I'm just looking for a push in the right direction, the above code is typed out and may not be syntactically correct.

I'm currently working on an SQlite3 server on Django, which will explain the usage of python.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show some example data.

Comment: What is the column that defines the sort order?

Comment: Sorry about the late reply, but I've found the solution.

It can be found [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96143/trying-to-a-lag-a-column-in-sqlite).